# Kafka Streams: Lag (delay) generated by store computation on manual join

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams topology where a session store is created through DSL aggregation. (All topics here are co-partitioned).

I later use this store from a `transformValues` on a different topic (`orders`), querying this store to produce a join-like output containing one order and its sessions.

However, the store produces lag on computation when there's some volume spike, while the `orders` topic doesn't. So, even if events are reaching the system in order, the `order` will not find its `sessions` in there.

So, when the order arrives, the store is sometimes not yet populated with previous, not-yet-processed data, so when looking up in the store, it does not find any entry.

I can see the solution of joining `order`'s `KStream` with a `KStream` version of the session store, in order to be able to act on both arrival of an `order` and of a `session`, generating new versions.

But that adds complexity and also IIRC the join will create an extra windowed topic (I already use that session store in other places so I still have to have it).

Are there any other strategies to solve it, and which trade-offs are to be made?

Comment: What version are you using? Maybe upgrading to 2.1 resolve your problem (it has improved timestamp synchronization for input topics that might avoid the issue).

Comment: I'm using 2.0. So, which improvements are done there? Which KIP/JIRA is it?

Comment: This one: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-353%3A+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization

Comment: I understand I'm doing `left Stream-Table`: 
```Stream-Table (inner and left):
time synchronization will be guaranteed via setting the above config value
out-of-order records are not handled (ie, we don't check for out-of-order record and just process all records in offset order): produces unpredictable results```
So this would guarantee time sync, but still would have incorrect results if records are out-of-order in the input topic, right? 

If I want to guarantee out-of-order arrivals, then I still should convert table to stream and perform `Stream-Stream inner join` ?

Comment: Stream-Stream join will change your semantics. Thus I don't think you want to use it. The best bet would be, to implement a custom operator via `transform()` that implements the join behavior you want. We plan to handle out-of-order data better in future releases out-of-the-box, so stay tuned.

Comment: It does indeed change semantics... however I tried playing with the setting, to no improvement (my processing actually got stuck when I set it to Long.MAX in a case where two subsequent timestamps differed greatly - as I see in docs this is expected). 
I am actually doing a transform that performs that join - but in that case, if the table to join with is not populated enough yet, I'll produce incorrect data and I'll not be able to react when data arrives to table. Am I right?
(also think of scenarios of bulk data import).

Comment: I ran a test on a subset of data. Pacing the data at 20 events per second (test env: one machine, docker containers; no repl, 3 partitions per topic, 455/755 orders found some sessions, as opposed to ~200/755 (non deterministic) when doing "bulk import" (producing 168K test events with no delay). So, lag still makes a difference (I went up to 30000 ms for MAX_TASK_IDLE_MS_CONFIG but same results).

Comment: Well. It's a hard problem... As said, we are planning to handle this case out-of-the box in future releases.

Comment: Thanks, will keep an eye. I think I have some kind of workaround though, at least for my case. Which is: 1) defer order check on sessionStore to after sessioning (including `order` in the sessioning). This does not guarantee but should help deferring the checking point in time. 2) After sessioning, the session will look up in an orderStore (which keeps List of Orders) and if any Order happened AFTER this `session`, then it will trigger re-check for that `order`, posting a newer version of this relation. Will post update when implemented and proven.